# how to integrate all columns from one table into one column of another table using mysql

Tags: mysql, database

table 1: employee

```
name| mobile| location
alex| 123   | australia
john| 456   | paris
kohl| 678   | australia
```

table 2:employment

```
id|location |data
1 |australia|[{"name":"alex","mobile":"123"},{"name":"kohl","mobile":"678"}]
2 |paris    |[{"name":"john","mobile":"456"}]
```

i have two tables named "employee" and "employment".  How can i get all the column values of employee table into one column of employment table as shown in table 2. I am new to SQL querying. I honestly don't have any idea on how to proceed. Any pointers and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to. Look up how to use a `JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution using `CONCAT` and `GROUP_CONCAT` to get this result:

```
SELECT location, CONCAT("[", GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{"name":"', name, '","mobile":"', mobile, '"}')), "]") AS data
FROM employee
GROUP BY location
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab25ee/2/0

To `JOIN` the `employee` table with the `employment` you can use the following solution:

```
SELECT employment.id, employment.location, CONCAT("[", GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{"name":"', name, '","mobile":"', mobile, '"}')), "]") AS data 
FROM employment INNER JOIN employee ON employment.location = employee.location 
GROUP BY id, location
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12f9c9/1/0